# Address Validator - String Java

Tags: java, string

Given an certain address like this:

```
Avenue Liberty, nº9-4º, 45644-521 Delph
```

Basically:

Information regarding the street, number of building, etc.,
**one comma one space 5 digits-3 digits one space**
and the city

I want the zipcode to have "**one comma one space 5 digits-3 digits one space**"

```
public String getZipCode(String line) throws IOException {
        if(line== null) {
            return null;
        }
        
        String[] parts = line.split("[\\s]+");

        String zipCode= null;
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            String part = parts[i];
             if (part.matches("\\d{5}-\\d{3}")) {
                    zipCode= part;
                    break;
                }
        }
        
        if (zipCode == null) {
            System.out.println("No zipcode valid for the line: " + line);
        }
        
        return zipCode;
    }
```

It won't validate if I put: Avenue Liberty, nº9 45644-521 Delph

Ignores the comma and accepts as valid

I really don't care about the other info, just the zip code having the **one comma one space 5 digits-3 digits one space**

Comment: The question is not clear to me. In your example, do you want the method to return `45644-521`?

Answer (score 2):

As you split on space, you cant' validate anything expecting a space in it, as every item of `parts` don't contain any

You just need a regex on the whole string, but use `Pattern` because `String.matches` only gives you a boolean, you also need to extract the zipcode then

```
public static String getZipCode(String line) {
    if (line == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String zipCode = null;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(", (\\d{5}-\\d{3}) ").matcher(line);
    if (m.find()) {
        zipCode = m.group(1);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No zipcode valid for the line: " + line);

    }
    return zipCode;
}
```

```
System.out.println(getZipCode(null)); // null
System.out.println(getZipCode("Avenue Liberty, nº9-4º, 45644-521 Delph")); // 45644-521
System.out.println(getZipCode("Avenue Liberty, nº9 45644-521 Delph")); // null
```